# Sass / CSS files getting ignored -- Asset Pipeline issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

So, of course I figure this out after an hour of messing with my main SASS file and wondering why I couldn't see the changes -- but it turns out that my local host isn't paying any attention to what I'm putting in my SASS files anymore.

This comes just after having switched everything over from SCSS to SASS, and I'm 100% sure the file is just getting ignored. For kicks/proof, I deleted all the styling in my application.erb.sass file (the only one with any styling any more -- I consolidated to get to the bottom of this), then saved, then restarted the server, and it's looking as styled as ever.

This seems to be an asset pipeline issue, and since I don't really know what to do with my config files, I'll paste the relevant-seeming stuff here:

**config/environments/development.rb** has these lines:

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

**config/application.rb**

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end



# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Also, I've got "gem 'sass-rails'" in my gem file, not in any group.

Think that's all/most that's relevant. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you paste your application.css file?

Comment: Actually, I figured out my problem. I think part of it was the need to precompile (though I'm still worried about the regularity with which I might have to do that). The other problem was in the order of the extensions on the css file. I'd tried application.erb.sass and application.erb.css.sass, but css.erb.sass worked. I guess you put the one you want it to finally compile into on the left -- didn't know that. Weird that it wasn't throwing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the extension on my css file (which had some embedded ruby):

erb.sass and erb.css.sass didn't work, but **css.erb.sass** did.

This was inexplicably stopping the file from being read, so that when I ran assets:clean/precompile, there was no css left. Before I ran that, I guess it was running my pre-compiled CSS file from before. Weird.

Apparently, these things must be compiled from the right to the left (as probably everybody but me knew), so CSS should be the type it's compiled into.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

run : rake assets:clean && assets:precompile

Comment: So this is a one-time solution, right? What's causing the problem, and will this fix it permanently?

Comment: Also, wouldn't I have to run rake assets:precompile after every update?

Comment: Also, actually, running those two has now somehow eliminated all of my styling. If I restart the browser, it's just the HTML without any of my CSS. (And the Inspector console gives a 404 application.css not found error).